# In Plone 4.1, How to fetch LDAP users from a specific group?

Tags: filter, ldap, plone

I am trying to integrate LDAP with Plone 4.1. I have successfully added plone.app.ldap through buildout. I can fetch all the users. But I want to fetch users of a group and not all. Where can I set filter for users? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

This product may help you

PAS Groups From LDAP:
http://plone.org/products/pasgroupfromldap

Comment: For Plone 4 the successor pas.plugins.ldap is recommended.